# Schema Object “title” member using Springfox

Tags: api, spring-boot, swagger-2.0, springfox

I am using Springfox to write documentation for an Api and I am having some problems generating the documentation site using Dapperdox http://dapperdox.io because it requires that the optional schema object property “title” is present. http://dapperdox.io/docs/spec-resource-definitions  - Is there a way to add the “title” property to a definition or a response using Springfox?  [title member schema definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fs9vk.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From an issue opened and later closed in the Springfox repository on GitHub, currently it is not possible to add “title” to the Schema Object using Springfox. This functionally should be part of next release!

https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2139